# Variable in a page, is it shared?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Basically I have 1 set of admin pages. I can use a session variable with each users GUID, to make sure to edit the proper DB information.

If there are say 5 people editing a page that uses for example an `ArrayList`, will the `ArrayList` be shared by all people editing it, or will each version of the page have its own local `ArrayList`? Do I need to make everything session variables of some kind so data does not get mixed up with that of other users?

Comment: Basically my question is whether or not each person who is viewing a page has their own instance of it, or if something like a single array or arraylist would accept data from multiple people, and thus I need to store variables differently. There really isnt any code to go along with this other then something like ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

Comment: Inside an arraylist that global within the page.

As a note: I dont have anything working, im just wondering before I get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET. The page is rendered every time you ask to. If you create an `ArrayList` inside, it will be alive only for that particular page render cycle. It will be lost as soon as the page is rendered.

Using `static` variables inside your page to keep variables alive is a bad idea since they will keep alive over sessions. Regular variables will be gone as the page render cycle ended. If you want to persist data for the user's session only, use the [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx) object to save the [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question! I did not know about the static variable part (which I wasnt planning on using anyway), but it was really useful extra information.

I will make this the answer in 5 minutes when it lets me.