# Using static lists vs static variables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-variables, static-variables

```
//ASP.NET.. Using GridListCache as global variable for single user
public static List<GridItems> GridListCache = new List<GridItems>();
```

In ASP.NET I am using a global static list to keep track of grid items.

Will this list remains specific to each user or will it be at the AppPool Level and shared across all users.

I definitely know for a fact that `public static int flag = 0;`  will be shared across all users. But when i used the list declared above i have not noticed it begin shared across all users and being specific to each user but i wanted the experts to weigh in on this and let  me know if putting this list in Session variable is the right way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thanks for your responses I am now using the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("GridListCache", GridItems, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, null);
```

Things seem to be working fine. Any comments on the settings that i am using for the cached value?

Thanks once again for your useful comments.

Comment: " is the right way to accomplish this." What is it that you're looking to do??

Comment: Static objects will be shared across all users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359876/variable-in-a-page-is-it-shared

Comment: And, being mutable, one user may remove an item from the list that another is depending on.

Comment: I was trying to keep a local copy of the grid list items which i get from the DB to perform time certain local tasks like sorting and other such activities in which case i don't need to make a call the DB again.

Comment: Then you need to store that in session state so that each user will have his own list. And don't declare it static!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Per-user" information** should be stored in Session state or custom storage that allows to pick data based on user identity.

Note that caching large amount of data in session state may actually decrease performance is it consumes too much space (in-memory state) or need to be serialized on each request for out-of-process sessions state like SQL/state server.

**Static fields** are always shared across all requests in the same application (on same machine for multi-server cases). As such they should be used to store static data that does not depend on user identity like list of countries/states. Additionally since it is shared across all requests it may require synchronization (i.e. using `lock`) if data structure is mutable (i.e. you can add more countries to list/dictionary).

It is often better to use .Net in `Cache` class instead static variables as it allows automatic expiration/refreshing of data and let you unload unused objects from memory.